# Why does the three points follow by making the two assumptions about the conditioned intensity function?

Tags: pr.probability

The intensity function is defined as

$$\lambda^*(t)=\frac{f(t|H_{t_n})}{1-F(t|H_{t_n})}$$
where $f$ is the density function and $F$ is the distribution function, and $H_{t_n}$ is the history of all the previous points of $t$ up to $t_n$.
Moreover, there is proven that $F(t|H_{t_n})$ is also given as:

$$F(t|H_{t_n})=1-e^{-\int_{t_n}^t\lambda^*(s)ds}$$.

An assumption is then made, saying that

1. $\lambda^*(t)$ is non-negative and is integrable on every interval after $t_n$.
2. $\int_{t_n}^t\lambda^*(s)ds \to 1$ for $t \to \infty$.

It is then said that hence the three points follows:

1. $0 \leq F(t|H_{t_n}) \leq 1$
2. $F(t|H_{t_n})$ is a non-decreasing function of $t$.
3. $F(t|H_{t_n}) \to 1$ for $t \to \infty$

Can someone explain to me how these three points follow given the two assumptions above? Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing the paper you start with who shall answer your question? Is there a underlying stochastic process? What?

Comment: @DieterKadelka Doesn't point number 1 follow from the stated definitions/assumptions without needing further information on the underlying process?

Comment: Yasmin: in its current form, the question might be more suitable for http://stats.stackexchange.com just because it is using terminology/definitions/conventions that are tacitly understood in that setting.

Comment: For a start, if you have tried to derive point 1 from the given information, at which point did you get stuck?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Of course number 1 can be answered without knowing anything about the underlying model. But I think it's always good to define anything which is not standard. I still do not know: Is the underlying model a point process or is it reliability theory or something else? Maybe you can answer this immediately, I can't. And maybe it's unimportant in this context.

Comment: I hope this is the answer you are looking for. The paper is about temporal point processes, more specifically, evolutionary temporal point processes (In other words, the present event (point) is dependent of the previous event(s)). This is a proof I'm trying to understand. I just can't seem to find the correct arguments to state why these two assumptions imply the three points.

Comment: Moreover, this proof's objective is to show that $F$ is in fact a cumulative distribution function (which thus is proofed by giving the three points). I hope this made it more clear.

Comment: Rather than just answering what the paper's about, why not also mention the specific paper?

Comment: Yasmin: given that some function $F(t)$ has the form $1- e^{-h(t)}$ where $h(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$, it should be clear that $0\leq F(t)\leq 1$ for all $t$. This seems to give point 1 and I think that points 2 and 3 will follow from similar reasons. If further explanation is required then I think http://math.stackexchange.com might be a more appropriate site to get help with such arguments

Comment: Yemon Choi: Thank you that makes sense. I'll oplaod my question in math math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: By the way, would it be considered wrong to say that, $F \to 1$ for $t \to \infty$, as $e^{-\int_{t_n}^{t}\lambda^*(s)ds} \to 0$ for $t \to \infty$? Because does it not do that?

Comment: @LSpice: Sure, the paper I'm reading is in this link https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00221.pdf, and the proof, or the proposition, is in page 9.